# Proof $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{1+k}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}$ by induction.

Tags: real-analysis, summation, induction

I'm trying to show the following formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{1+k}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}$$

I have already verified the formula with $n=1$, now I continue with the induction:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2} \\
\rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k} +\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$$

But now I have no idea how to get $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+k}$, I have been trying a lot of algebra or changing the index but I don't see the "magic" step. Any idea is welcome!!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2050413/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1358798/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3902097/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B2n%7D%20(-1)%5E%7B1%2Bk%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D%20%3D%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2Bk%7D%24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}&=\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{n+1+k}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+k}= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}-\frac1{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}$$

$$\begin{align}
-\frac1{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}&=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\Rightarrow \\\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you want $-\frac{1}{n+1}$ on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\dots= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k} +\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}=\\=\left(\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+k} -\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}=\\=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+k}$$